# set the value of select option dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my code. I am  trying to set the value of select tag from database. but it's not working as expected. My requiremnet is value='Auto' then 0th index should be selected else 1sst index should be selected. But its not happening that way. can some one help me?

```
  <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="medium mb-1" for=""> Select Mode of Update </label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="avupdatemode" value="<%= data.updatemode %>" >
                                <option value="Auto" >Auto Update</option>
                                  <option value="Manual">Manual</option>
                                        </select> 
                          </div>
    <script> 
      var sel= document.getElementById('avupdatemode');
      if(document.getElementById('avupdatemode').value =='Auto'){
    sel.options.selectedIndex = 0;}
    else{
        sel.options.selectedIndex = 1;   
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: your backend is jsp ?

Comment: No.. Sails Js with Mongo DB

Answer (score 1):

First there is no `id` attribute on your select.

Second `.value` will take the value from the selected option and not the `value` attribute from the select.

So i've added `data-value="sAuto"` to the select and then done `document.getElementById('avupdatemode').dataset.value == 'Auto'`

**DEMO**

```js
  var sel = document.getElementById('avupdatemode');
  if (document.getElementById('avupdatemode').dataset.value == 'Auto') {
    sel.options.selectedIndex = 0;
  } else {
    sel.options.selectedIndex = 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="medium mb-1" for=""> Select Mode of Update </label>
  <select class="form-control" id="avupdatemode" name="avupdatemode" data-value="sAuto">
    <option value="Auto">Auto Update</option>
    <option value="Manual">Manual</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am using sails js and I am having the value in my database for avupdatemode and I am fetching it from db and bringing it to my ejs page as <%=data.updatemode %>.  I want to display that value in my select option.  Suppose if my avupdatemode in DB is "Auto" then 0th index should be selected. or else 1st index should be seletced.  But your suggestion is not working that way

Answer (score 0):

I am getting my backend data in an array to my ejs page.
So I tried this and it worked:

```
var sos = <%- JSON.stringify(sos) %>;
```

I iterated the array and based on the value i set my index for the select option.